# TYPO3 10 Solr scheduler baseVariants domain name

Tags: solr, typo3, typo3-10.x

Scheduler task "Index Queue Worker (solr)" works correctly for baseVariant testing.mydomain.nl when started **manually**.

However when the task is running **automatically** [www.mydomain.nl](http://www.mydomain.nl) is used. This I can see in the TYPO3 solr log under /var/log

How to configure using the corresponding baseVariant domain name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a condition for the baseVariant checking for an environment variable (like `TYPO3_CONTEXT`) which is set using the webserver configuration or .htaccess. That means they're not set when the script is run through cronjob (or CLI). You can set the variable by adding `VARIABLE=value` before the command, so for example: `TYPO3_CONTEXT=Development /path/to/my/htdocs/vendor/bin/typo3 scheduler:run`